# What happens when a thread calls longjmp() in c

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

What happens when you have a thread that calls `longjmp` in the c language. I know that when a program is on a single thread the `PC` is placed back to the address when the `jmp_buf` was created and the processor's registers are restored to that point in time.

1. If a `setjmp` is called inside the thread and then `longjmp` is called, everything might be OK?
2. What if `setjmp` is called before any threads exist and then a thread calls `longjmp` on that `jmp_buf`, does it kill all the other threads since they didn't exist when the `jmp_buf` was created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The POSIX specification for relevant functions can be found at:

- [`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html)
- [`setjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html)
- [`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html)
- [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)

Note that the specification for `longjmp()` lists some of the restrictions:

> The `longjmp()` function shall restore the environment saved by the most recent invocation of `setjmp()` in the same process, with the corresponding `jmp_buf` argument. If the most recent invocation of `setjmp()` with the corresponding `jmp_buf` occurred in another thread, or if there is no such invocation, or if the function containing the invocation of `setjmp()` has terminated execution in the interim, or if the invocation of `setjmp()` was within the scope of an identifier with variably modified type and execution has left that scope in the interim, the behavior is undefined. [CX] ⌦ It is unspecified whether longjmp() restores the signal mask, leaves the signal mask unchanged, or restores it to its value at the time setjmp() was called. ⌫

For your scenarios:

1. Should be OK.
2. Undefined behaviour.  If instead the main thread (or the thread that called the `setjmp()`) does the `longjmp()`, it should be OK, but it won't kill other threads.  You're likely to run foul of the general restrictions on `longjmp()` even so.

Overall, be sensible and very conservative.  They're fragile functions.  Don't use them unless really necessary, and worry about resource management in general.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, so we can assume that if you embed the `jmp_buf` in a `struct` created by the thread itself instead of declaring it globally, there should be no problem, right? I mean this case: https://github.com/davranfor/c/blob/master/json/src/json_schema.c#L847 being the `jmp_buf` reference a member of the `struct`: https://github.com/davranfor/c/blob/master/json/src/json_schema.c#L22

Comment: @DavidRanieri: From what I can see, as long as either `valid_schema()` or `raise_error()` (or a function that they call) is what calls `longjmp(schema->error)` — assuming the same argument name is used in the called functions — then the code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was a bit worried as I have seen very few implementations encapsulating `jmp_buf` in a `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to let a language lawyer say for certain, but I suspect it'll lead to undefined behavior if you attempt to `longjmp()` from a thread to a `jmp_buf` created by a different thread.

My reason for this is that the two threads will generally have completely distinct stacks, and on MSVC x64 at least, `setjmp()` saves `rbp` and `rsp`, which are pointers into the current stack.  The net result of this is that the thread that calls `longjmp()` will come out of `setjmp()` with it's stack pointer and frame pointer pointing into the middle of the stack of the other thread.

There's no way on planet earth that this situation can end well.

Comment: My thoughts exactly on things not ending well. One could argue there isn't much that goes on under the hood in C that you can't control, but some specific things like this can be a bit of a mystery.